# Undelete different phrasing

Tags: support, status-completed, exact-duplicates

This question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5138/what-do-i-do-with-excess-dacite-and-alunite-etc

Was deleted because it is a duplicate.  In my opinion it should be undeleted and closed as duplicate so that people with a similar query will be linked to the correct answer.

Close as duplicate is there for a reason, please don't delete your duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree.
<sub>also, I wanted to add a status-* tag for the first time</sub>